# Assigning a struct to a local variable in GLSL

Tags: glsl

Is there any way to assign a struct to an instance variable in GLSL? The standard says you can construct a struct like so:

```
light lightVar = light(3.0, vec3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
```

... but I'm unable to copy a struct. I've tried a lot of variations of the following:

```
#version 420
...
in Vertex
{
    vec4 color;
    vec4 position;
    float distanceFromScanner;
    bool isInBody;
} vertex[];
...
Vertex va = Vertex( vertex[0] );
// Vertex va( vertex[0] );
// Vertex va = Vertex( vertex[0].color, vertex[0].position, vertex[0].distanceFromScanner, vertex[0].isInBody );
```

They all give me unexpected token syntax errors like this:

```
error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting \"::\" at token \"=\"
```

Am I missing something? Is there anything I can do, other than always using `vertex[0]` ?

This is on a GeForce GTX 770 with NVIDIA driver 335.23, FWIW.

Comment: There's no point in doing `Vertex(vertex[0])`; `vertex[0]` is already a `Vertex` object.

Comment: is there anything wrong with `Vertex va = vertex[0]`?

Comment: @UnholySheep that one also causes a syntax error. It was the first one I tried. *should* that work?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'm not doing `Vertex(vertex[0])`. I'm doing `Vertex va(vertex[0])`, which in C++ is a copy construction.

Comment: But this isn't C++, its GLSL. Besides, that's not what your uncommented code is doing.

Comment: You don't show the entire shader code. Are your attempted assignments within the `main()` function? You can't have assignments outside of a function.

Comment: yes, they're within the `main()` function.